# Different totals for queries with multiple dimensions in Google Analytics data using googleanalyticsR

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-r

I'm analyzing Google Analytics 4 data using the R library googleanalyticsR.
I can't figure out why changing the combination of dimensions results in consistently different absolute numbers. For example, the query with or without sessionsMedium gives me two different session numbers.

```
sessions <-ga_data(
  my_property_id,
  dimensions = c("date"),
  metrics = c("sessions"),
  date_range = c(from_date, oggi),
  dim_filters = ga_data_filter("country"=="Ireland"),
  limit = -1)

tot_sessions <- sum(sessions$sessions)

# 956 sessions

sessions_with_medium <-ga_data(
  my_property_id,
  dimensions = c("date","sessionMedium"),
  metrics = c("sessions"),
  date_range = c(from_date, oggi),
  dim_filters = ga_data_filter("country"=="Ireland"),
  limit = -1)

tot_sessions2 <- sum(sessions_with_medium$sessions)

#959 sessions
```

It's not an issue with those specific dimensions because the same happens, for instance, with the query for 'date' or for the combination of 'date' and 'region'.
Could it be a sampling problem? From what I've been able to understand, though, it shouldn't be the case because the website visits aren't numerous, and the reports on Google Analytics appear as non-sampled.
Also, in this example, the difference in numbers is small, but in other combinations, it becomes much larger.

Just to add further detail, I've tried running the same queries from https://ga-dev-tools.google/query-explorer/ and the results are the same. Therefore, I don't think it's an issue with the R library.

What could it be due to and how can I resolve it